# 500 (Internal Server Error) and SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 when using fetch function

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

I have a laravel api when I test it with postman it works very good, but when I try to make a post request using fetch() in js it returns 500 error internal server error and SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0.

here is my js code

```
function send() {
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/login', {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(userData),
            headers: {
                "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
            }
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => console.log(json))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

Comment: Check what that requests returns. It's not JSON. It's most likely HTML of an error page.

Comment: If it returns a 500 Internal Server Error, than the response is no good anyway. Look at what the server-side error is.

Comment: So you need to check what the error is on the server.

Comment: If your api request works with postman but not with js, then you are sending different requests. Show both versions of the request you are sending, complete with all headers and body.